# Downgrade ios 10.3.2 to 10.3 in iPhone 6s

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to connect iOS device to Xcode. My Xcode version is 8.3.3 and iPhone's iOS version is 10.3.2 so this iOS version is not compatible with Xcode.

For this problem I thought to downgrade my iPhone OS from 10.3.2 to 10.3.

Is it possible to downgrade iOS version? then please let me know, how to downgrade? or suggest better option.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading an iPhone without [IPSW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPSW) file is impossible. I would recommend you just update Xcode to latest version, that will easily fix your problem :)